# npm install gives error: js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall: `npm run-script ./cyclic.js`

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I do have npm(3.6.0), node(v5.6.0) installed on ubuntu 14.04.

I am getting below error while I am running `npm install` :

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-77-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall: `npm run-script ./cyclic.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall script 'npm run-script ./cyclic.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the js2coffee package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run-script ./cyclic.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs js2coffee
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls js2coffee
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sachin/angular_projects/demo/npm-debug.log
```

Anyone faced this issue?